# How to get my page to update an image when overwritten

Tags: java, image

I am attempting to overwrite and update an image on a page whenever my end user would like. They would simply upload a new image, and it will replace the old with the same file name and then the src path in the web page does not need to change. However, it kind of works. The file overwrites. but when I refresh the page the image does not change to the new. The odd kicker is, When I go into my IDE (Eclipse) and double-click the new image file, THEN I can refresh the web page and it shows the new replaced one. This is my first job project, and I have not found the answer elsewhere.I will provide the code;

`<img th:src="@{/img/uploadedFile.jpg}" alt="image"></img>`

```
    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST, value="image")
        public String processImageForm(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, 
            RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {


        if (file.isEmpty()) {
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message", "Please select a file to upload");
            return "redirect:image";
        }

        String extension = file.getOriginalFilename().substring(file.getOriginalFilename().lastIndexOf("."));
        Path path = Paths.get(UPLOADED_FOLDER + fileName + extension);

        try {
            Files.deleteIfExists(path);

        } catch (IOException | SecurityException e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        }

         try {
                // Get the file and save it somewhere
                byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
                Files.write(path, bytes);

               redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message", "You     successfully uploaded '" + file.getOriginalFilename() + "'");

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        return "redirect:image";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that you are not copying that file to the correct location.

You know that in a web app the the war file is created and then deployed on a server. So in order to change something you need to change it on the server (even when running from Eclipse it creates a server context from you). I guess that's where your problem comes from - you copy the file to the wrong place.

And when you are running from Eclipse the file is properly replaced on your local file system but this doesn't change the deployed war application. When you double click it in Eclipse it notices the change and automatically redeploys it for you basically changing the file on the server.

Comment: Makes sense. 2 questions on that; 1)If the above UPLOADED_FOLDER and fileName are the same every time (Code box cut it off). How is it going to a different place? 2)If that is the case. How would that be fixed?

Comment: Well it's the same place in your local environment but is it the same place where you deploy it? You should probably get the upload_folder path from the servlet container context - that would be the folder where that application is deployed. Maybe something like:   context.getRealPath("/");

Comment: I've refrained from deploying it to a server till it is working locally. So this so far is only locally. I realize I may have to use something other than a relative path once deployed. I just wanted to make sure I had everything else before adding to the deployed build. Is it possible the relative path there is now would work in the deployed version? So maybe adding it to the build might actually fix the issue?

Comment: Here's the cutoff part:                                                                        private static String UPLOADED_FOLDER = "src/main/resources/static/img/";                 
private static String fileName = "uploadedFile";

Comment: even locally it is the same but the servlet container is provided by eclipse